# How to exclude locally installed dependency from remote sonar scan

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My POM looks like this -->

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.abc.xyz</groupId>
      <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have installed abc.xyz jar locally inside .m2 and is not available on mvn artifactory.
When I try to scan my code using sonar scanner installed on remote server, it tries to download abc-xyz.jar from maven artifactory & fails.
How do I make my remote sonar happy?

I tried giving scope as system but I see that it is deprecated.
Tried following

```
 <scope>system</scope>
 <systemPath>${project.basedir}/path/to/abc-xyz.jar</systemPath>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sonar.exclusions in your pom.xml to exclude your jar-directory :

```
<properties>
    <sonar.exclusions>${project.basedir}/path/to/abc-xyz.jar</sonar.exclusions>
<properties>
```

You might also try to define the property <sonar.skip>true</sonar.skip> in the pom.xml of the module you want to exclude.

Or try advanced reactor options like so: `mvn sonar:sonar -pl !${project.basedir}/path/to/abc-xyz.jar`.